# Why is my component not getting re-rendered upon using setState and changing the value of state?

Tags: reactjs

Why is it that the component Eachcartitem is not getting re rendered although I change the state. I have this fucntion which gets called from inside the Eachcartitem component:-

```
cartremover(a){
     var cart1=cart;
     var firstpart=cart.slice(0,a);  
     var secondpart=cart.slice(a+1,cart.length);  
     var final = firstpart.concat(secondpart);   
     this.setState({
        cartstate:final,
        abc:true
     })
}
```

The Eachcartitem is used as follows in parent component:-

```
<div style={{float:'left',width:'65%'}}>
                {
                    this.state.cartstate.map((cat) => (<Eachcartitem data={cat} index={this.state.cartstate.indexOf(cat)} cartremover={i=>this.cartremover()}/>))               
                }
                <br></br><br></br>
            </div>
```

And the Eachcartitem is as follows:-

```
class Eachcartitem extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            data:this.props.data
        };        

    }

    clicker(){
        this.props.cartremover(this.props.index);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className='cartdiv'>

                <div style={{width:'100%',display:'inline'}}>
                    <h3 style={{width:'70%',float:'left',paddingLeft:'10px'}}>{this.state.data.productName}</h3>
                    <div style={{float:'right'}}>Rs.{this.state.data.productPrice}</div>
                    <div style={{width:'30%',float:'left',paddingLeft:'10px'}}>Store:{this.state.data.shopName}</div>
                    <div style={{width:'30%',float:'left',paddingLeft:'10px'}}>Quantity:{this.state.data.productQuantity}</div>


                    <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                    <div style={{width:'auto',float:'left',paddingLeft:'10px'}}>Variant:{this.state.data.variant.quantity}</div>
                    <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                    <div style={{width:'auto',float:'right',marginRight:'7px'}} onClick={()=>this.clicker()}>&#10060;</div>
                </div>

            </div>

        );
    }
 }
 export default Eachcartitem
```

But for some reason the cartitem divs are not getting changed why is it so?

Comment: Did you checked `cartstate` is updating or not?

Comment: yea cartstate is one element less as expected but no change in component

Comment: anything on console

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not passing the index of the item to the function, here:

```
cartremover={i => this.cartremover()}
```

Write it like this:

```
cartremover={i => this.cartremover(i)}
```

---

You don't need to pass the index to child component, use this code:

```
this.state.cartstate.map((cat, i) => (
    <Eachcartitem data={cat} cartremover={e => this.cartremover(i)} />
))
```

Now from `Eachcartitem` simply call that method: `this.props.cartremover()`.

Better to use `splice` to remove the element at particular index, write the method like this:

```
cartremover(a){
    let cart = [...this.state.cartstate];
    cart.splice(a, 1);

    this.setState({
        cartstate: cart,
        abc: true
    })
}
```

Check working snippet:

```js
const Temp = (props) => <div>
  {props.name}
  <button onClick={props.cartremover}>Delete</button>
</div>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {cart: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
  }
  
  cartremover(a){
    let cart = [...this.state.cart];
    cart.splice(a, 1);

    this.setState({
      cart,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.cart.map((cart, i) => (
          <Temp key={cart} name={cart} cartremover={e => this.cartremover(i)}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: but using the new method only the last element is getting removed always...i want to remove the array element on which it is clicked..not the last element/..

Comment: still removes only the last element :(

Comment: check the working snippet, let me know if you face any issue in that :)